# Given a position and rotation, how can I find a point that extends X distance from it?

Tags: math, three.js, geometry, trigonometry

I have a point in 3D space, and that point has an orientation. I want to get the end point of a line X distance from the origin point, following in orientation. How would I do this?

The answer doesn't have to be specific to any library, but I am using Three.JS.

Comment: How is this orientation represented?

Comment: @jsb Quaternions or Euler angles. Doesn’t really matter.

Comment: `let endPoint = new THREE.Vector3().copy(startPoint).setLength(needed_distance).add(startPoint);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to Three.JS, depending on what you're starting with, or your comfort, there are several solutions.

### Object3D

It provides you with extra utility methods that lets Three.js figure out the math for you:

```js
// Create an Object3D
const element = new THREE.Object3D();

// Set position and orientation
element.position.copy(startPosition);
element.rotation.copy(eulerRotations);

// Move "forward" by the desired distance
element.translateZ(distance);

// Now we have our final position!
console.log(element.position);
```

I think the key to your question is the `Object3D.translateZ()` method, [you can read more about it in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.translateZ).

### Vector3

Internally, what Object3D just did was Vector3 math. If you're only dealing with points and orientations, it might make more sense to use Vector3 directly:

```js
const finalPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 1)
  .applyQuaternion(quaternionRotations)
  .multiplyScalar(distance)
  .add(startPosition);
```

### Math

If you only want the math, this is what Three.JS is doing under the hood:

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let z = 1;

const ix =   quaternionW * x + quaternionY * z - quaternionZ * y;
const iy =   quaternionW * y + quaternionZ * x - quaternionX * z;
const iz =   quaternionW * z + quaternionX * y - quaternionY * x;
const iw = - quaternionX * x - quaternionY * y - quaternionZ * z;

x = ix * quaternionW + iw * - quaternionX + iy * - quaternionZ - iz * - quaternionY;
y = iy * quaternionW + iw * - quaternionY + iz * - quaternionX - ix * - quaternionZ;
z = iz * quaternionW + iw * - quaternionZ + ix * - quaternionY - iy * - quaternionX;

x = x * distance + originalPositionX;
y = y * distance + originalPositionY;
z = z * distance + originalPositionZ;
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```js
function ray(position, distance, direction) {
  const dy2 = 2 * direction.y;
  const dx2 = 2 * direction.x;
  const x = position.x + distance * (dy2 * direction.w + dx2 * direction.z);
  const y = position.y + distance * (dy2 * direction.z - dx2 * direction.w);
  const z =
    position.z +
    distance *
      (-1 * Math.pow(direction.y, 2) +
        Math.pow(direction.z, 2) +
        Math.pow(direction.w, 2) -
        Math.pow(direction.x, 2));

  return {x, y, z};
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This led me to the answer I was looking for. I updated your answer to include the vector math solution, too.